# Loading WSO2 IS in an iframe for Kibana Dashboard

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, kibana, saml, x-frame-options

I am trying to load a `kibana` dashboard in my application using `iframe` and implementing `saml sso` using `wso2 IS`.

Now, I want to load the wso2 IS in the iframe and have tried using the `X-Frame-Options` but it didn't help.

In the Kibana `config.yml` file, I have tried configuring the x-frame. Is there any particular solution to this or any particular configuration?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.